# Compose SVG crashed

Tags: android, svg, android-jetpack-compose

I have a vector drawable in my android project. I added the svg via Android Studio into my project.  When using the drawable my app crashes and I get the following Exception.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown command for: R
```

Other drawables work. The preview of the xml-File is also correct.

Using PainterResource or VectorResource do both not work.

```
Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_world),
      contentDescription = "")

Image(imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_world),
      contentDescription = "")
```

As other svg's work I guess the file has some corruptions.

Comment: https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/2749228/hello-i-am-trying-to-render-a-svg-like-that-image-painter-pa